# Does the rebuilding of St Nicholas church building pose a constitutional problem?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution

One of the buildings that got destroyed during the 9/11 attacks was the St Nicholas Greek Orthodox church. It is busy being rebuilt.

I'm assuming that some sort of government funding involved. Is there some constitutional concerns over a place of worship being built with government money?

I know the rebuild is part of New York's attempt to heal from the scars of a deeply traumatic event but is it actually legal for a place of worship to get built like that?

Edit

It seems under further investigation the Ports Authority of New York and New Jersey is funding the rebuild.

I have also seen that the building will have a secular bereavement room, although I'm not entirely certain I know what a secular room is meant to be.

Probably a room that has the logo of the American Secular Humanist Organisation on the wall instead of a cross.

[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Nicholas_Greek_Orthodox_Church)

Comment: "under further investigation..." Link?

Comment: I have added a source as requested

Comment: Quote the relevant lines from that link in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you assume "government" funding is involved?

From [Frequently Asked Questions | Saint Nicholas Greek Orthodox Church](https://stnicholaswtc.org/about/frequently-asked-questions/)

> The rebuilding of Saint Nicholas is being funded through “The Friends
> of St. Nicholas", a separate non-profit 501(c)3 that has raised the
> funds to complete the construction. Individual donations are welcome,
> and every donation will be permanently recorded in the Church.

501(c)(3)'s are perfectly legitimate: [501(c)(3) Organization Definition investopedia.com](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/501c3-organizations.asp)

Comment: The assumption that government funding is involved might be connected to the fact that $25 million in government funding is involved: https://cityroom.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/10/14/way-is-cleared-to-rebuild-greek-orthodox-church-lost-on-911/

Comment: That's for a "platform on which St. Nicholas will sit and provide the necessary utility hookups," which is not the church itself, and would be required infrastructure for any new building on the site, same as any other rebuilding taking place due to 9/11.

Comment: Yes, I also read the article that I linked to. How do any of those conclusions help answer the question?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch similarly, there are typically no issues with religious organizations and facilities receiving ordinary government services that are available to non-religious entities. For example, religious groups can register real estate, hold a tax certificate, register organization-owned vehicles, be licensed as a private child day care center, or sue in local courts.